# How do I control the speed of a simple DC motor based on the output of a machine learning algorithm using a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, control-system, python, motordriver

Let's suppose there is a simple machine learning algorithm for detecting speed limit signs using image recognition and it detects a 30 km/hr sign.  Is there any way to send instructions to my motor that is connected to my Raspberry Pi to spin it forward at 60 RPM? (for the project we assume 1 km/hr = 2 RPM.)

This is for a college project. I have the machine learning algorithm ready but I am unable to find a way to make the motor react to the output of the machine learning algorithm. If anyone could point me to similar projects or give any suggestions that would be much appreciated.

Here are the specifications of the software and hardware I am trying to use:

- Python and relevant machine learning libraries
- Raspberry Pi 3
- L298N 2 A motor driver module
- 300 RPM - 12V centre shaft DC geared motor
- Power source for the Pi and motor driver

Comment: First you do need a speed feedback sensor, then you have to execute the control with a deterministic time, i.e. time interrupt. The language doesn't matter, as long it produce a clean and fast machine code.

Comment: Use an off-the-shelf speed controller for the motor. It can likely be controlled with a voltage input (from a DAC) or a PWM input (from your pi, maybe?). Your project will be difficult enough without designing a speed controller.

Comment: Ah, let me see. Your question is in two parts: (1) An AI thing that can read a speed limit sign, and let Rpi3B+ know the speed limit. (2) The Rpi speaking python to tell the L298N by PWM (yes, Rpi GPIO pin in PWM mode) to move forward at 60 rpm. (3) The Rpi should also read the motor's encoder signals, usually interrupting Rpi by a Rpi GPIO pin in input mode, with call back function, triggered by the interrupt signal. All three parts above are more or less 1st/2nd year college IT level or average Arduino/Rpi hobbyist with a couple of hobbyist years of experience.

Comment: For college projects, I would recommend BLDC geared encoder motor, and not DC toy motors such as the yellowish TT130. For motor drivers, I would recommend any motor driver except L298N, which is for newbie hobbyists.

Comment: You're making a robot with 2.65m diameter wheels? Cool!